# Reducing number of factor levels before modelling

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a factor with 2600 levels and I want to reduce it to ~10 before modelling

I thought I could do this with an operation that says "if a factor is listed fewer than x times, it should be placed into a bucket called "other"

Here is some example data:

```
df <- data.frame(colour=c("blue","blue","blue","green","green","orange","grey"))
```

And this is the output I am hoping for:

```
  colour
1   blue
2   blue
3   blue
4  green
5  green
6  other
7  other
```

I have tried the below:

```
df %>% mutate(colour = ifelse(count(colour) < 2, 'other', colour))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>         Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "factor".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is actually a nice package in the tidyverse called `forcats` which helps in dealing with factors. You can use `fct_lump`, which does exactly what you need:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(colour = fct_lump(colour, n = 2))
#>   colour
#> 1   blue
#> 2   blue
#> 3   blue
#> 4  green
#> 5  green
#> 6  Other
#> 7  Other
```

Comment: This is elegant and can be applied to multiple columns at the same time - eg `mutate_at(vars(colour, size, style, department), funs(fct_lump(., n = 2)`

Answer (score 5):

with `tidyverse` functions, you can try something like:

```
df %>%
  group_by(colour) %>%
  mutate(cnt = n()) %>%
  mutate(grp = if_else(cnt >= 2, as.character(colour), as.character("Other"))) %>%
  select(-cnt)
```

which gives (here, the threshold value being `>= 2`)

```
  colour grp  
  <fct>  <chr>
1 blue   blue 
2 blue   blue 
3 blue   blue 
4 green  green
5 green  green
6 orange Other
7 grey   Other
```

Comment: You don't need to use two 'mutate()'. It can be under the same one.
df %>%
  group_by(colour) %>%
  mutate(cnt = n(),
         grp = if_else(cnt >= 2, as.character(colour), as.character("Other"))) %>%
  select(-cnt). 
And you need to add 'require(tidyverse)'. As you use %>% and 'if_else' and not 'ifelse'

Comment: yep, but I find this makes it more readable :). Just a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

A base R approach using `replace` and `ave`

```
df$colour <- as.character(df$colour)
replace(df$colour, ave(df$colour, df$colour, FUN = length) < 2, "Other")

#[1] "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "green" "green" "Other" "Other"
```

Here we calculate the `length` of each group (`colour`) and `replace` the values with "Other" where the `length` is less than 2.

If you want you can convert `colour` back to factors using `as.factor` before applying your model.