# Filter factor variable based on counts

Tags: r, regression

I have a dataframe containing house price data, with price and lots of variables. One of these variables is a "sub-area" for the property, and I am trying to incorporate this into various regressions. However, it is a factor variable with almost 3000 levels.

For example:

```
table(df$sub_area)

La Jolla    
2

Carlsbad
5 

Esconsido 
1
```

..etc

I want to filter out those places that have only 1 count, since they don't offer much predictive power but add lots of computation time. However, I want to replace the sub_area entry for that property with blank or NA, since I still want to use the rest of the information for that property, such as bedrooms, bathrooms, etc.

For reference, an individual property entry might look like:

```
ID Beds Baths City     Sub_area     sqm... etc   
1   4     2    San Diego   La Jolla   100....
```

Then I can do

lm(price ~ beds + baths + city + sub_area)

under the new, smaller sub_area variable with fewer levels.

I want to do this because most of the predictive price power is contained in sub_area for the locations I'm working on.

Comment: See if this is it: [Reducing number of factor levels before modelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504804/reducing-number-of-factor-levels-before-modelling). Or maybe this one [Reduce number of levels for large categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066382/reduce-number-of-levels-for-large-categorical-variables?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
areas <- names(which(table(df$Sub_area) > 10))
df$Sub_area[! df$Sub_area %in% areas] <- NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new dataframe with the number of occurrences for each subarea and keep the subareas that occur at least twice.

Then add `NA`s to the original dataframe if the subarea does not appear in the filtered `sub_area_count`.

```
library(dplyr)

sub_area_count <- df %>% 
  count(sub_area) %>% 
  filter(n > 1)

boo <- !df$sub_area %in% sub_area_count$sub_area
df[boo, ]$sub_area <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give a reproducible example, but I think this will work for identifying those places which count==1

```
count_1 <- as.data.frame(table(df$sub_area))
count_1 <- count_1$Var1[which(count_1$Freq==1)]
```